# How to apply custom keys to my sequential array/collection of arrays using Laravel or PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-collection

I'm trying to apply custom keys to a collection in laravel.

The best way that I found was using functions like `transform` or `mapWithKeys`.

```php
$result = $collection->map(function ($item) {
    return [
        'custom_key_name_1' => $item[0],
        'custom_key_name_2' => $item[1],
        'custom_key_name_3' => $item[2],
    ];
});
```

I was hoping to find something like:

```php
$keys = ['custom_key_name_1', 'custom_key_name_2', 'custom_key_name_3'];
result = $collection->withKeys($keys);
```

Do you know any other way to do that with a less verbose code?

I'm working in a legacy Laravel 5.5 project.

**Input Example**

```php
$collection = collect([
    [ 'first', 'second', 'third' ],
    [ '1', '2', '3' ],
    [ '1st', '2nd', '3rd' ],
]);
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
  [
    'custom_key_name_1' => 'first',
    'custom_key_name_2' => 'second',
    'custom_key_name_3' => 'third',
  ],
  [
    'custom_key_name_1' => '1',
    'custom_key_name_2' => '2',
    'custom_key_name_3' => '3',
  ],
  [
    'custom_key_name_1' => '1st',
    'custom_key_name_2' => '2nd',
    'custom_key_name_3' => '3rd',
  ],
]
```

Comment: There is no other way, what is the issue with that code? Is it that overbosed for you?

Comment: @matiaslauriti yeah, it seems unnecessarily verbose for me. Anyway, thanks for clarify that, I thought that there was a less-code way.

Comment: No worries, but belive me that that code is not overbosed at all. It may not be the best one, but it is pretty good. Maybe you would like to create a macro for a Collection, so you create your own `withKeys` (following your example) and end up with the same stuff. Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#extending-collections)

Comment: What do you not like? That you have to do `$item[0], $item[1], ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with a collection of arrays, you can use PHP's [`array_combine()` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to put the keys and values together:

```php
$collection = collect([
    [ 'first', 'second', 'third' ],
    [ '1', '2', '3' ],
    [ '1st', '2nd', '3rd' ],
]);
$keys = collect(['custom_key_name_1', 'custom_key_name_2', 'custom_key_name_3']);

$result = $collection->map(fn ($v) => $keys->combine($v));

dump($result);
```

Result:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#5189
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "custom_key_name_1" => "first"
      "custom_key_name_2" => "second"
      "custom_key_name_3" => "third"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      "custom_key_name_1" => "1"
      "custom_key_name_2" => "2"
      "custom_key_name_3" => "3"
    ]
    2 => array:3 [
      "custom_key_name_1" => "1st"
      "custom_key_name_2" => "2nd"
      "custom_key_name_3" => "3rd"
    ]
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

The important caveat being that, per the documentation, "a ValueError is thrown if the number of elements in keys and values does not match."

Comment: I'm marking that as right answer because I don't think we'll find anything better nowadays. The combine option reduces the boiler plate, but it isn't optimal yet. Initial code calls just `map` while the answer calls `map+combine`, anyway, thank you for the help.